# Dashboard Designer in SP 2013

Tags: dashboard-designer-2013

Where is the Dashboard Designer in SharePoint 2013? From where should I open it?

Answer (score 3):

I tried my self...

I simply Activated **Performance Point Service Site Features** and **SharePoint Server Publishing** at Site Features and Activated **Performance Point Service Site Collection Features** and **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** feature at Site Collection Features and then in the BI Center site -> on Data Connections page I found the PerformancePoint tab where there was a Dashboard Designer.