# Where can I found and How can I configure BI Center Site Collection SharePoint Online 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I try to configure KPI and states lists - but they are not supported on SP Online 2013.

How I can configure BI Center Site Collection SharePoint Online 2013? I created new sub-site (and new site collections).  And... it all. I don't know where to start. Most information is about SharePoint Server.

[Dashboard Designer in SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62441/dashboard-designer-in-sp-2013/62449#62449) - this not many information.

Answer (score 3):

If I where you I would set up a new Site Collection with the Business Intelligence Center template and start to configure it using the guide [Set up a BI Center site in SharePoint Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198236(v=office.15).aspx). Then I would continue to read [Business intelligence capabilities in Excel, SharePoint Online, and Power BI for Office 365](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198235(v=office.15).aspx) to see what my options are. If I need to evaluate BI template vs. Power BI I would read [Compare a BI Center site to Power BI for Office 365 sites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn394343(v=office.15).aspx).

For more on hands work I would read both [Data sources supported for workbooks in SharePoint Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169563(v=office.15).aspx) and [File size limits for workbooks in SharePoint Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn394344(v=office.15).aspx).

Later on when my BI center is up and running I would consider to enable mobile views reading [View workbooks in SharePoint Online on mobile devices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn394342(v=office.15).aspx).

[image]

Hopefully this is a start on your BI Center quest in Office 365/SharePoint Online